# Intermittent InstanceOwnerException with WF4

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I'm running workflows in worflow foundation 4 with SQL Durable instancing for persistence.

Sometimes, I'm getting System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstanceOwnerException when resuming a workflow.

```
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstanceOwnerException occurred

  Message="The execution of an InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted because the instance owner registration for owner ID 'd2db07fd-f31d-458c-be53-de163d5db8d4' has become invalid. This error indicates that the in-memory copy of all instances locked by this owner have become stale and should be discarded, along with the InstanceHandles. Typically, this error is best handled by restarting the host."

  Source=System.Runtime.DurableInstancing

  StackTrace:
       à System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
       à System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstancePersistenceContext.ExecuteAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
       à System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstancePersistenceContext.OuterExecute(InstanceHandle initialInstanceHandle, InstancePersistenceCommand command, Transaction transaction, TimeSpan timeout)
       à System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstanceStore.Execute(InstanceHandle handle, InstancePersistenceCommand command, TimeSpan timeout)
       à System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.PersistenceManager.Load(TimeSpan timeout)
       à System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.LoadCore(TimeSpan timeout, Boolean loadAny)
       à System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Load(Guid instanceId, TimeSpan timeout)
       à System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Load(Guid instanceId)
```

Is there a way to avoid this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually the result of a previous run not completing normally and being restarted before the original lock expires. Is this happening as the result of a edit/debug/edit cycle or in a production environment?

You can adjust the lock period using the HostLockRenewalPeriod setting. Keep in mind that setting it to a real low value is normally not a good idea.

Comment: You are right, it happened while debugging. 

If I understand correctly, the persisted Workflow instance was locked by a previous execution that did not release the lock correctly. I can limit this problem by lowering the HostLockRenewalPeriod so that the lock expires faster, but the workflow engine will then refresh its lock more often, which causes more load on the database.

Comment: I just thought I would check, but you can tell if the original lock expired by the `SurrogateLockOwnerId` being null (when using `SqlWorkflowInstanceStore`), or is there more you need to check?